# Umbraco Distributed Cache not updating public instances

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a few Hangfire jobs running in the background and importing external data into Umbraco V7. This is running in a load balanced setup, with a master instance and a couple of public ones. The Hangfire jobs only run in master.

The issue is that the changes to the data don't update the cache of the public instances. I have found that the instructions that trigger the update of the distributed cache are not being saved in the 'umbracoCacheInstruction' table so the public instances don't have a clue that there's new data to sync.

My main guess is that the distributed cache is listening for events to happen in the Content Service and these are not triggered because I am using a fake Umbraco content.

Anyone has a clue about if there's anything specific to do with that context to trigger the handlers? Or maybe the problem is somewhere else?

Comment: please take a look at CacheRefresherEventHandler.cs file. You will find event handlers and what events are needed to fire them. I would first ensure they are fired.

Notice that many methods in ContentService (I believe you use ContentService to import new data?) has raiseEvents param. Ensure it;s not set to false.